# Optimizing nearby locations MYSQL query via Spatial Indexes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize my SQL query to display the nearest locations.

Originally I was using the following query

```
SELECT name,path, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-36.848461) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(174.763336) ) + sin( radians(-36.848461) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM cityDB HAVING distance < 200 AND path IS NOT NULL
```

This query uses the longitude / latitude values to calculate the distance and takes 14.5 seconds to complete (too slow!)

I created a spatial index (point) of the longitude / latitude values in an effort to speed up the query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT name,
  (ST_Length(ST_LineStringFromWKB(
    LineString(
      pt,
      ST_PointFromText('POINT(174.763336 -36.848461)', 4326)))))
  AS distance
FROM CityDB
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 99
```

However this is averaging 23seconds even longer than the first query which really surprised me!

Is there something else I should be doing with my query to speed it up?

The only thing that I got to get it below 1 second was to add this (thanks to this post [Improving performance of spatial MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128379/improving-performance-of-spatial-mysql-query))

```
    longitude BETWEEN longpoint - (50.0 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint)))) 
AND longpoint + (50.0 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
```

However there are a couple of bugs in the code. If I chose Fiji, it will only display locations < 180 latitude, If I chose Vanuatu it will only choose locations < -180 latitude.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT name, (ST_Length
(ST_LineStringFromWKB(LineString( pt, ST_PointFromText('POINT(-179.276277 -18.378639)', 4326))))) 
AS distance FROM CityDB 
WHERE longitude BETWEEN -179.276277 - (50.0 / (111.045*COS(RADIANS(-18.378639)))) AND -179.276277 + (50.0 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(-18.378639)))) 
GROUP BY (name) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 99
```

In addition to this, it will also display locations in Russia which is miles away (I know that we can add a limit to distance but there must be a better way than this)

Any other efficient ways to make such a query?

Comment: Share the table structure

Comment: Just like in the question you linked to, use `ST_distance` (or `ST_distance_sphere`) instead of your `ST_Length`.

Comment: Hi there, tried using st_distance still 18seconds to run the query (SELECT name, st_distance(pt, POINT(174.763336, -36.848461)) as distanceRaw FROM CityDB ORDER BY distanceRaw LIMIT 50)